# Is there a way for me to use the standard Result<T, E> type inside a Substrate module?

Tags: rust, substrate

Substrate already defines its own result type as `Result<(), &'static str>` and doesn't let me use the generic type. How can I use the Rust standard `Result<T, E>` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use the Rust standard Result type in a module's private function, but not the dispatchable function.

You need to import it first by `use rstd::result`, then use it like `result::Result<your-value-type, your-error-type>`.